# How setHeader() works in Apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I was going through some documentation on Apache Camel and not able to understand what `setHeader()` does in Apache Camel. Does it add a header to the file specified within `from`. And also suggest some link where I can get tutorial on Apache Camel.

Answer (score 7):

No, it does not add anything to a file. `.setHeader()` creates a header that exist within the current route. You can create a header like `.setHeader("myHeader", "myHeaderValue")`. Use headers to access dynamic properties during your route by `.getHeader("myHeader")` For more long lasting property use exchange properties.

Answer (score 4):

`setHeader` to a file(message) consumed(`from`) does not set the header to the file.

[Camel File2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) *check the Message Headers*. This lists all the Message Headers supported for produce(to) and consume(from) of File endpoint. For a file consumed, you can access the (`getHeader`) supported headers in the message. But overwriting these values does not overwrite the meta data of the file though.

Headers and Properties in Apache Camel can be used interchangeably to pass values between processes in a single `route`, but when you want to carry across different routes the behaviors differs. Headers can be lost at endpoints basically as they usually represent some component specific things. Go through the document to understand further.

Best tutorials for Camel - [Apache Camel Books](https://camel.apache.org/books.html) and [Apache Cammel Documentation](https://camel.apache.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that in Camel you are working with Exchange object and that object has headers, properties, body.in, body.out etc.

So when you are writing `from(“file:...”)` content of your file will be putted into your Exchange’s `body.in` and then you can get your file’s content for example in Processor using `exchange.getIn().getBody()`.

Headers are part of your Exchange, so when you are writing: `exchange.setHeader(“headerExample”,”MyHeader”)`, it will add header of existing Exchange’s headers.

Comment: Exchange doesn't have headers. Exchange.In has.

Comment: Where do you put the "exchange.setHeader(“headerExample”,”MyHeader”)", is it before the camelContext.start() or on the get route bean/process?  I want to add the "myjwt:token" authentication I need to access an http route.

Answer (score 0):

See [Message.setHeader(String name, Object value)](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.7.0/org/apache/camel/Message.html#setHeader-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-):

> Sets a header on the message

Looking at [*Return Address* of the Enterprise Integration Patterns (EIP)](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ReturnAddress.html) we find:

> A *Return Address* is put in the header of a message because it’s not part of the data being transmitted.

We can also look at [RFC2045, 3. MIME Header Fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-3):

> MIME defines a number of new RFC 822 header fields that are used to describe the content of a MIME entity.

And we can even look at [RFC1866 – Hypertext Markup Language - 2.0, 5.2. Head: HEAD:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-5.2):

> The head of an HTML document is an unordered collection of information about the document.

All the same concept: Storing metadata together with the payload.